# Python: Which is faster: matching lists or matching dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, match

I have two large lists. Each of them consists of lists:

```
list_1 = [[1, "BMW", "Boston", "01Jan2013"], [37, "Chevrolet", "Denver", "05Jan2013"],
[854, "BMW", "Boston", "01Jan2013"],...]

list_2 = [[1, "Mercedes", "Boston", "01Jan2013"], [37, "Chevrolet", "Denver", "05Jan2013"],
[854, "Toyota", "Boston", "01Jan2013"],...]
```

Inner lists always have same item types.

Now I want to match each inner in `list_1` with one in `list_2`, using inner lists' item 1, item 3 and item 4. That is: serial number, city origin and date. These keys are always same with list_2. An inner list in `list_1` can only have 0 or 1 match in `list_2`.

What is the most pythonic and fastest way to do this? Should I convert lists into dictionaries?

Comment: Can `list_1` contain duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN TERMS OF SPEED, you will probably want to make use of a dictionary. It seems that one way or another, you will need to iterate over a list. Dictionaries are of course faster than iterating over a list, so you could make at least one of your lists into a dict. (I tested the following solution with 200,000 entries just like yours in two separate lists, and my speed averaged 0.109999 seconds to completion. Lists were way beyond that mark.) You probably won't come close to that if you just try to use lists or tuples, unless the order of your entries allow you to use something like zip. Your serial numbers seem to be unique, so the following would work (by iterating over one list and then compare items 1, 3, and 4 [in positions 0, 2, and 3] to values in a dictionary):

```
list_1 = [[1, "BMW", "Boston", "01Jan2013"], [37, "Chevrolet", "Denver", "05Jan2013"],
[854, "BMW", "Boston", "01Jan2013"]]

list_2 = [[1, "Mercedes", "Boston", "01Jan2013"], [37, "Chevrolet", "Denver", "05Jan2013"],
[854, "Toyota", "Boston", "01Jan2013"]]


dict_2 = dict()

for elem in list_2:
    dict_2[elem[0]] = elem[1:]

for item in list_1:
    if dict_2[item[0]][1:] == item[2:]:    # Have to offset the index since dict list only has three elements
        print item


[1, 'BMW', 'Boston', '01Jan2013']
[37, 'Chevrolet', 'Denver', '05Jan2013']
[854, 'BMW', 'Boston', '01Jan2013']
```

Once you convert the second list into a dictionary, you will only have to iterate through one list to get your results. This solution will return the entire sub-list of each match from list_1, which you seem to want. If you want the full matching sub-lists from both lists, this would work:

```
for item in list_1:
    if dict_2[item[0]][1:] == item[2:]:
        print item, [item[0]] + dict_2[item[0]]


[1, 'BMW', 'Boston', '01Jan2013'] [1, 'Mercedes', 'Boston', '01Jan2013']
[37, 'Chevrolet', 'Denver', '05Jan2013'] [37, 'Chevrolet', 'Denver', '05Jan2013']
[854, 'BMW', 'Boston', '01Jan2013'] [854, 'Toyota', 'Boston', '01Jan2013']
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `list_1` can't contain duplicates (as per your comment), you could convert it into a `set` of `tuple`s instead of a list of lists. That way, you could efficiently check if a certain item is in the set by using the `in` operator.

You need to use tuples instead of lists because lists are mutable (and therefore not hashable), so they can't be put into a `set`. The same would apply if you used a `dict`, but a `set` seems to be more suitable for your use case (it's not clear what you'd use as the key for the `dict`).

Comment: tuples are unmutable? Please clarify.

Comment: @JoSo You cannot change a tuple (e.g. add an item) once you've created it. That makes them usable as `dict` keys or as part of a `set`.

Comment: `t = (1, 2, 3); s = t; t += (4,); print s` -- As you see, the original tuple is unchanged, your code creates a *new* tuple by initializing it with the values contained in `t`, concatenated with `4`, and then re-assigns the variable `t`. Also, [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-immutable) explicitly states that tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a key function specifying the field to compare by:

```
def item_key(item):
    return tuple(item[i] for i in [0, 2, 3])
```

It should be hashable so that you can use it as a dict key.
The you can create a mapping from an item key to the item itself, or a list of items if different items can share the same key.

```
key_to_item2 = dict((item_key(item), item) for item in list2)
```

Now you can test each item in *list1* against the dict.

```
for item1 in list1:
    item2 = key_to_item2.get(item_key(item1))
    if item2 is None:
        # no match found
    else:
        # item2 in list2 matches item1 in list1
```

This approach can be easily adjusted for using other fields for matching and for multiple matches support.

Answer (score 1):

What is the "best" solution depends on what you want. If it's about speed, then depending on the size of your input a dictionary might be the best idea.

If it's about clarity and brevity, I think it's very pythonic to stay with lists and do the following:

```
result = []
for l1 in list1:
    result.append([l2 for l2 in list2
                   if l1[0] == l2[0] and l1[2] == l2[2] and l1[3] == l2[3]])
    assert(len(result[-1]) in [0,1])
```

Comment: There is no `where` keyword in Python, you probably mean `if`.

Answer (score 1):

A solution similar to that of @omz would be to convert the lists to dictionaries.  The dict key would be the tuple `(serial,city,date)` (items 1, 3, and 4), and the value would be the other field, 'make' (item 2).  Then to match them, just iterate through the keys of `list_1` (now `dict_1`), attempting to retrieve the corresponding member of `dict_2`:

```
dict_1 = {(1, "Boston", "01Jan2013"):"BMW", (37, "Denver", "05Jan2013"):"Chevrolet", (854, "Boston", "01Jan2013"):"BMW",...}

dict_2 = {(1, "Boston", "01Jan2013"):"Mercedes", (37, "Denver", "05Jan2013"):"Chevrolet", (854, "Boston", "01Jan2013"):"Toyota",...}

for k in dict_1:
    match = dict_2.get (k, None)
    if match is not None:
        print "Match found:", match
    else:
        print "No match"
```

Naturally, what you do when you find a match won't be what I've written, but that should serve to show how you can find the matches.